# Assigning values to a list vs an array and ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, syntax

Why does assigning values to a `List` have to be done with `Add` but to an array it can be done with the `[]` operator?

For example:

```
    string[] y = new string[10];
    y[0] = "asdf"; //fine

    List<string> x = new List<string>(10);
    x[0] = "asdf"; //ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Shouldn't both have the same behavior?

Comment: `Shouldn't both have the same behavior?` No. Why it should be the same? They are not the same thing...

Comment: You need to add the string "asdf" to x first before you can use it.  x.add("asdf").  Now the list is empty.

Comment: Why would you assume they'd have the same behavior? Lists and arrays are different things.

Comment: I was under the assumption that a c# `List` is the same as c++ `vector`.

Comment: @kuhaku it's the same idea however the implementation doesn't have to be the same.

Comment: @kuhaku You are free to write a class that implements `IList<T>` that has the same behaviour...

Comment: This is actually a good question.  Lists have an indexed property, so why shouldn't you be able to instantiate it with a capacity of 10 and then use the index to set the value?  Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code for List(of T), your see that the indexed property getter/setters look like this:

```
    // Sets or Gets the element at the given index.
    //
    public T this[int index] {
        get { 
            // Fllowing trick can reduce the range check by one
            if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) { 
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(); 
            }
            return _items[index]; 
        }
        set {
            if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(); 
            }
            _items[index] = value; 
            _version++; 
        }
    }
```

Notice that, before setting the corresponding item in the List's internal array, it first checks the private `_size` variable to make sure it is in range.  `_size` is not set to the size of the array, however.  Size is incremented/decremented in the List's various Add/Remove methods, so even if you instantiate a list with an initial capacity of 10, that is the *internal* capacity of the List's array.  Here is the constructor:

```
    // Constructs a List with a given initial capacity. The list is
    // initially empty, but will have room for the given number of elements 
    // before any reallocations are required. 
    //
    public List(int capacity) { 
        if (capacity < 0) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
        _items = new T[capacity];
    }
```

The `_size` is not set (and therefore remains as its initialized value of 0) unless you either use Add/Remove/AddRange/etc. or use the constructor that accepts an IEnumerable (in which case the size because the number of items in the IEnumerable).

It makes sense if you think about it.  The idea of a list is so that you DON'T have to worry about the complexity (and ugliness) of numeric indexes and resizing/copying arrays when the capacity needs to change.  The size of the internal array, after the List is instantiated, should be of no concern to the developer.  If you want to micromanage how the internal array is utilized, then you should either create your own implementation, or just use an array.

Answer (score 1):

The internal structure of a list is different of an [`array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx). While in a [`array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) you have a size of items defined on its definition, the amout of memory necessary to have these objects is realocate in memory by the CLR.

In a [`list<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) you can define the maximum of items in a list. That is (*part of*) the reason you have to call the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add objects in a [`list<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). You can define a initial [`Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) for a list as you did on the constructor. If you need to add more than the capacity, the list will rearrange it for you. The framework manages for you how much items you have on the list.

Another important thing is that in both cases, you can access by `index`. For sample:

```
var obj = list[1];
var obj2 = array[1];
```

In a case that you do not have the `1` index on the [`list<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), in an [`array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), you get the `default(T)` (considering `T` as your type) and in a list you will get an [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The way I like thinking about it is when you initialize an array you have a group of boxes.  When you initialize a list with a size parameter, you have a warehouse that can hold a group of boxes (but no boxes there until you Add() them)

Comment: Thank you @Steve, you are right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The statements "The internal structure of a list is different of an array," and "but it will not realocate in memory," are not accurate.  A list, internally IS an array.  The List class is simply a wrapper around it that handles resizing, copying, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The way you implemented your array is right.

The size of an array needs to be declared when it is created. There is no way around that.

However, Lists' sizes are more flexible. You can add as many elements as you want without having to declare an initial size. After you've added elements however, you can access or edit them through their index number. Here's an example.

You are getting that exception because technically the list doesn't fill an index until you actually add a value to it. Let me know if that clears it up.

```
    //You can add your elements when you instantiate it
    List<string> names = new List<string>{"Alex", "Tommy", "Bob"};

    //Or you can add them later
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();

    cities.Add("Denver");
    cities.Add("New York");

    //Now that they are created you can access or edit any of the elements within them.
    names[2] = "Gerard";
    cities[1] = "San Francisco";
```

Answer (score -2):

This constructor does not create any elements in list. It just reserves memory for items that could be added to this list.
You still have to insert items to the list manually before you can use then this way.

Upd:
This overload could help you when you dealing with large collections and you almost sure that you'll put about N items into your list. Thus you can reserve memory on creation and avoid memory allocation while you add items into this list (which could be slow sometimes).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the quest though.  The question is why, if a list is created with a specific capacity, can't that capacity be accessed.  Initializing an array with a capacity of 10 also does not actually add anything to the array, but you can still explicitly assign each element immediately after an array is created.